# Maxima: How to replace the variables to simplify the equation?

Tags: maxima

```
(%i1)   r: sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2);
(r) sqrt(z^2+y^2+x^2)
(%i2)   dx: diff(r,x);
(dx)    x/sqrt(z^2+y^2+x^2)
```

I just show a simple code because my code is long and complex.

I want to simplify `dx` and get the result is `x/r` not `x/sqrt(z^2+y^2+x^2)`.

However, I can't find the useful command.

Could somebody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, you can use `subst`, although `ratsubst` is probably useful in a greater number of cases.

```
(%i1) linel:65;
(%o1)                          65
(%i2) r: sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2);
                             2    2    2
(%o2)                  sqrt(z  + y  + x )
(%i3) diff (r, x);
                               x
(%o3)                  ------------------
                             2    2    2
                       sqrt(z  + y  + x )

(%i5) subst (r = 'r, %o3);
                                x
(%o5)                           -
                                r
(%i6) ratsubst ('r, r, %o3);
                                x
(%o6)                           -
                                r
```

Note that the single quote mark prevents evaluation, so that `'r` is the symbol `r` instead of the value of `r` (namely `sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)`).

Comment: If ```dx``` is complex eqn( like ```-7*x*(z^3-3*z*r)/r^(9/2)-y*z/r^8;```), the result is very ugly by ```ratsubst```. Is there any other better skill to use it?